# How to optimize searching in a MySQL table when using OR?

Tags: mysql, search, search-engine

I recently learned that I can search in a MySQL table across multiple columns by using the following select statement with OR:

```
SELECT * data WHERE TEMP = "3000" OR X ="3000" OR Y="3000";
```

Which returns the results needed, but it does take approximately 1.7 s to return the results in the table that has only ~260k rows. I also have already added indexes for each of the columns that are searched.

Is there a way to optimize this query? Or is there another one which is faster but returns the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use UNION...

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE TEMP = "3000"
UNION
SELECT * FROM data WHERE X ="3000"
UNION
SELECT * FROM data WHERE Y="3000";
```

...however the real key to improving the performance is firstly indexes and second the query analyser.  Often the data determines which is faster as TEMP may be a hundred times less likely that Y to be "3000" - so that should be first in you original OR statement for example.

Comment: Hmm, I am getting a syntax error `near data where TEMP ="3000"`. But I got your point about the query structure. For this query, the column TEMP is likely to give back results with 3000.

Edit: please add `from` to the answer. The result is 0.05 second. I believe this could be the best I can get.

Comment: @AhmedAl-haddad sorry for that - it was untested and I'd missed the FROM keyword!

Comment: I wanna verify something, if I change the query from `TEMP=3000` to `TEMP>3000` or `TEMP<3000`, it takes a huge amount of time (10s~)to get the results. How do  I counter this? (The returned result is more than 200K of rows)

Comment: Or, could you tell me where I can read more on this to know what's the appropriate query for each need? It seems that whenever I change some of the values I significantly different speeds.